# Get the value of a string that matches a Regex

Tags: regex, typescript

How to replace a string that matches a regular Expression in typescript

Here is my regular expression and string that matches the given pattern should be replaced as in the code

```
let formattedString = result.replace(/^<p>(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?/img, '<p><a href=$1 target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer">$1</a>');
```

the result I've is - `<p>demo.test.io</p>`

Now I want to replace this one as - `<p><a href="demo.test.io" target="_blank">demo.test.io</a></p>`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the pattern a bit by matching the protocol and optional s and otional www.

Then use the first part of the pattern and replace the optional parts at the end, with matching any char except the angle brackets.

Note to put the double quotes around group 1.

```
^<p>((https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5})[^<>]*<\/p>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/en5uqz/1)

```js
let result = "<p>demo.test.io</p>";
let formattedString = result.replace(/^<p>((https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5})[^<>]*<\/p>/img, '<p><a href="$1" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer">$1</a>');
console.log(formattedString);
```